# Checkboxes in Javascript

Tags: javascript, function, checkbox, count

Here's the deal.  The task is to write a function which should be able determine the number of checkboxes checked for each question and prompt a user if more than 3 answers were selected. 
I have a total of 8 questions and each question has 4 to 8 answers, in the checkbox format. 
This is what I came up with:

```
function countChecks(){
   var m = 0;
   var n = 0;
 chk = document.getElementsByName("DSelectionID");

  for(var i=0; i<myitems.length i=""></myitems.length>
   var value = myItems[i];

  for(n = 0; n < value.length; n++) {
 if(value[n].checked)  {
  m++;
 }
 }
 return m;
 }
```

the above function works fine for one question and returns 'm' to the main function, which handles it this way:

```
var check = countchecks();

if (check > 3)
 alert ("more than 3 checkboxes were selected");
   else { 
 //do the thing 
}
```

to traverse all the 8 questions this is what I came up with:

```
 function countChecks(){

   var m = 0;
   var n = 0;
```

//this captures id's for the right questions

```
 chk = document.getElementsByName("DSelectionID");
 chk2 = document.getElementsByName("DSelectionID2");
 chk3 = document.getElementsByName("DSelectionID3");
 chk4 = document.getElementsByName("DSelectionID4");
 chk5 = document.getElementsByName("DSelectionID5");
 chk6 = document.getElementsByName("DSelectionID6");
 chk8 = document.getElementsByName("DSelectionID8");
 chk9 = document.getElementsByName("DSelectionID9");

  var myItems = new Array();

  myItems[0]= chk;
  myItems[1]= chk2;
  myItems[2]= chk3;
  myItems[3]= chk4;
  myItems[4]= chk5;
  myItems[5]= chk6;
  myItems[6]= chk8;
  myItems[7]= chk9;
```

//loops through all the questions
    for(var i=0; i
      var value = myItems[i];

//loops through the checkboxes for each question

```
 for(n = 0; n < value.length; n++)
  {
  if( value[n].checked)
  {
      m++;
     if (m > 3) {
    return false; 
   }
  }
 }
   }
}
```

and the main body handles it like this:

```
var check = countChecks() 
if (check == false)
alert ("more than 3 checkboxes were selected");
   else {
//do the thing
  }
```

It is something very simple I'm missing in the countChecks() function 
Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [jquery](http://jquery.org) would make this pretty trivial

```
if ($('#yourform input[type=checkbox]:checked').length() > 3) {
   alert('More than 3 checked');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`chk = document.getElementsByName("DSelectionID");` does not grab the ID, it grabs a reference to the element in the DOM.

To get the ID you need to use:

```
chk = document.getElementsByName("DSelectionID").getAttribute("id")
```

Comment: It returns a DOM NodeList, which is basically an array of matching elements, actually.